# Software that improves system performance?

Tags: performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer Speedup](https://superuser.com/questions/53670/computer-speedup)

Do you know of any software or application that can optimize the computer and make it run into its fullest performance?
Tune up utilities is good but do you know of any other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing you are talking about Windows-

I would ignore pretty much everything available that says it can speed up your machine as a lot of them are just a load of rubbish.

Personally, I would start by removing any and every application that is no longer used then use [Microsoft/Sysinternals Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and delete every entry of programs that I no longer use.

If you are using Vista or Windows 7, your hard drive should Defrag on schedule. If using XP set this on schedule or do it at least once a month.

Next, if you really want some extra speed, start disabling services for items you do not use - for example, if you use static IP - disable DHCP service etc... These do hardly anything, but every little helps.

Also, make sure if using anti virus, you are using a good fast engine such as [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/Security_Essentials/). I cannot begin to tell you how much of a difference this can make and how slow some anti virus software can make your machine.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your drives are all defragged propperly, this will improve your system-speed.

and if you want power over looks, turn off all visual effects and themes, this costs lots of processing power